# We define a map $d_{p} : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $d_{p}(x, y) := (x - y)^{2p} \cdot (x^{2p} + y^{2p})$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, metric-spaces

We defines a map

$d_{p} : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}  $

by

$d_{p}(x, y) := (x - y)^{2p} \cdot (x^{2p} + y^{2p})$.

Now, we want to find a function $C : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for any natural number $p$ and any real numbers $x$, $y$, $z$, we have

$d_{p}(x, z) \leq C(p) \cdot (d_{p}(x, y) + d_{p}(y, z)).$

**My work**

I am thinking of  Bit of a cryptic/vague I am thinking of recommend case distinctions as early as possible and NOT trying to find optimal constants as the analytic expressions are very messy. If anyone can prove such a constant exists for slightly weaker assumptions on x,y,z,

[image: complex attempt]

i was going to try to factor out the dz/dx and make it f(x,z) + g(x,z)dz/dx = something and then set f(x,z) = g(x,z) = 0 but i think it will not work

im trying to find a simplification of the numerator that's always larger, a simplification of the denominator that's always smaller, and the ratio is still bounded
or maybe those always's hold outside of something like the unit circle or the 2x2 square
but then i would have to prove the max doesn't happen inside that area
i do think (2,1,-1) probably is the best as p approach infinity
and the C limiting to 3^(2p-1)

Need solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swapping $x$ and $z$, if needed, we can assume that $|x|\le |z|$. Let $s=|z|$ and $t=|z-x|$, so $t\le 2s$.
Then $$d_p(x,z)=t^{2p}(|x|^{2p}+|z|^{2p})\le 2t^{2p}s^{2p}.$$

Put $\lambda=1-\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. Note that $\lambda=(1-\lambda)(1-2\lambda)$.

Let $y\in\mathbb R$ be any number.

Suppose that $|y-z|\ge \lambda t$. Then
$$d_p(y,z)=(y-z)^{2p}(y^{2p}+z^{2p})\ge (\lambda t)^{2p}s^{2p}\ge \lambda^{2p}d_p(x,z)/2.$$

Suppose that $|y-z|\le \lambda t$. By the triangle inequality, $|x-y|\ge (1-\lambda)t$. Moreover,
$|y|\ge |z|-\lambda t\ge s-2\lambda s.$
Then $$d_p(x,y)=(x-y)^{2p}(x^{2p}+y^{2p})\ge$$ $$((1-\lambda)t)^{2p}((1-2\lambda)s)^{2p}\ge$$  $$((1-\lambda)(1-2\lambda))^{2p} d_p(x,z)/2.$$

So we can pick $C(p)=\frac{2}{\lambda^{2p}}=\frac{2}{((1-\lambda)(1-2\lambda))^{2p}}=2(2+\sqrt{2})^{2p}$.

For the lower bound on $C(p)$ put $x=1$, $y=0$, and $z=1$. Then $d_p(x,y)=d_p(y,z)=1$ and $d_p(x,z)=2^{2p+1}$, so $C(p)\ge 2^{2p}$.

Comment: Why did you take $t=|z-x|/3$ ?

Comment: @Martin This was the first good guess. Now I am adjusting the value of $t$.

Comment: Ohh now I understand